# nested foreach loops to insert data in mysql using php

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I have very little experience in php. I am trying to insert two array values with nested **foreach** loop. Then inside foreach loop value is inserting multiple times. I have multiple text boxes and select list as below.

```
<div>    
    <input name="crew_name[]"  type="text" />
    <select name="crew_role_id[]">
        <option value="1">Hero</option>
        <option value="2">Actress</option>
        <option value="3">Actor</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>    
    <input name="crew_name[]"  type="text" />
    <select name="crew_role_id[]">
        <option value="1">Hero</option>
        <option value="2">Actress</option>
        <option value="3">Actor</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And i have php code as below.

```
$crew_names = $_POST['crew_name'];
foreach ($crew_names as $key => $value) {

    $crew_name = $value;                                        

    $crew_role_ids = $row['crew_role_id'];
    foreach ($crew_role_ids as $key => $value) {

        $crew_role_id = $value;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO crew_movie (crew_name, crew_role_id) VALUES ('$crew_name', '$crew_role_id')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }       
}
```

Now **$crew_role_id** is inserting two times as it is in inside the foreach loop of foreach loop.

Please suggest me solution also please excuse me if my English is poor.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This code doesn't insert anything because the query is never run.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd also strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.

Comment: @IncredibleHat That got ninja'd in there four minutes ago.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: as $key => $value

You have this in both the inner and outer for each loop. These will conflict. Use different names for the second set.

Comment: some one posted the answer and removed it before i vote. that was working  for me. thanks a lot for your help.